# user receipt issue php

Tags: php, receipt

I'm working on making a receipt for my registration code and I keep getting this error:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

```
<?php
// (2)gather details of CustomerID sent
$customerId = $_GET['CustomerID'] ;
// (3)create query
$query = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = $customerId";
// (4) Run the query on the customer table through the connection
$result = mysql_query ($query);
// (5) print message with ID of inserted record
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
print "The following Customer was added";
print "<br>Customer ID: " . $row["CustomerID"];
print "<br>First Name: " . $row["Firstnames"];
print "<br>Surname: " . $row["Surname"];
print "<br>User Name: " . $row["Username"];
print "<br>Email: " . $row["Email"];
print "<br>Password: " . $row["Password"];
}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_fetch_array%28%29+expects+parameter+1+to+be+resource%2C+boolean+given

Comment: Fix your damn SQL injections. And `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter ` ALWAYS MEANS  THERE IS AN ERROR IN YOUR QUERY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error messages means that `$result` respective `mysql_query()` didn't return a valid resource.

Please try `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`. By the way I don't see a `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()`!

**Warning:**

Your code is very insecure (**-->SQL injection**)!

Please escape all data coming from `$_GET` or `$_POST` via `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `intval` (if it is an integer!).

Comment: yeh i forgot the connection...thank you. what do you mean by escape all data?

Comment: If `$_GET['CustomerId']` is for example `0 OR 1=1`, your query will be `SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = 0 OR 1=1` and this will select all data from your table! You can also run other commands like deleting some tables! Please search for `SQL Injection`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$result = mysql_query ($query);
```

With this and see what error happens:

```
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: ok thank you. so i fixed my original problem but now when am directed to the reciepts page i get this error instead: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near " at line 1. line 1 is include "connection.php";

Comment: never mind i wasnt looking at the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You must first connect to your Database Server and select the database on which you wish to work.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['CustomerID']) )
{
  $customerId = $_GET['CustomerID'] ;

  $con = mysql_connect("your_db_address", "db_username", "db_password");  
  if(!$con)
  {
     echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
     exit;
  }

  $db  = mysql_select_db("your_db_name");
  if (!$db)
  {
     echo "Unable to select DB: " . mysql_error();
     exit;
  }

  /* Rest of your code starting from $query */
}
?>
```